# php custom C++ module works from command line, not on webserver

Tags: php, c++, zend-framework, swig, lighttpd

I made a custom PHP module with C++ and Swig. It works from the command line, but not with my webserver:

```
php index.php
php-cgi index.php
```

Both of those work fine.

I'm using lighttpd and php. I didn't configure these in any special way. I just installed them using sudo apt-get install.

Unfortunately if I make a webpage I get this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function minikey_to_wif() in /var/www/index.php on line 6
```

Calling function_exists("minikey_to_wif") returns False too.

The phpinfo() does not show my module called minikey, and shows the same configuration path as the file I edited (/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini):

```
extension=/path/to/php-ext/minikey/minikey.so
```

I also tried copying it to where the other PHP extensions seem to be installed (/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/) but that didn't work either.

I've been stopping, and starting lighttpd countless times. Each time, when I run ps aux | grep php, there are no results. I've also rebooted a few times to no effect. I have no idea what's up.

Comment: Maybe a trivial hint, but did you restart your webserver? And you're testing test.php in commandline, and index.php in the browser?

Comment: yes I restarted many times, and rebooted my computer several times.

Answer (score 2):

OK found the answer.

The extension relied on a library which was installed in a non-standard location. Normally I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in ~/.bashrc. But when the web server ran the extension, it didn't have that environment variable.

Fix was to create a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/genjix.conf with /home/genjix/usr/lib and run ldconfig as root.

Answer (score 0):

Try running phpinfo() using lighty. Make sure that its pointing to the correct php.ini.

If you think this is the problem you can launch php using the -c switch from inside lighttpd.conf with `"bin-path" => "/path/to/php-cgi -c /path/to/php.ini"`:

e.g.

```
fastcgi.server = (
    ".php" => (
            (
                    "bin-path" => "/path/to/php-cgi -c /path/to/php.ini",
                    "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket",
                    "max-procs" => 4,
                    "idle-timeout" => 30,
                    "bin-environment" => (
                            "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "4",
                            "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "1000"
                    )
            )
    )
)
```